# IPhone parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app)

I have the following json:

```
NSString *jsonResult = @"{\"code\":\"000\",\"message\":\"success\",\"datas\":[{\"datas\":[{\"service_name\":\"user_info\",\"name\":\"Account Test 32\",\"number\":123,\"company\":\"ABC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"balance\":\"1000\",\"profit\":\"-80.00\",\"credit\":\"0.00\",\"equity\":\"1000.00\",\"leverage\":100,\"free_margin\":\"1000.00\",\"free_margin_mode\":1.0,\"server_name\":\"localhost\",\"stopout_level\":5,\"stopout_mode\":0}],\"service_name\":\"user_info\"}]}";
```

Can anyone give an example how to parse this?

Comment: Why are you parsing JSON? Is that the payload you get from a webservice?

Comment: yes it is the payload from the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Import [SBJson parser](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) you could use [TouchJson](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) also but I prefer SBJson.

```
#import "JSON.h"

// Create SBJSON object to parse JSON
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

// parse the JSON string into an object - assuming json_string is a NSString of JSON data
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:jsonResult error:nil];
```

Comment: how do i get the value inside the datas array ?

Comment: You have got your `jsonResult` right? pass that to the JSON parser. It will convert to ObjectiveC objects... that's what you need right? So what i have written is the parser part. Where you import the json parser & parse the string....

Comment: It still got me an error: SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [json objectWithString:jsonResult error:&jsonError];
NSDictionary* jsonValue = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"code"];
NSLog(@"code: %@", [jsonValue objectForKey:@"code"]);

Comment: so its working? why posting the code?

Comment: Not working. sorry for posting the code.

Comment: How is it not working? Its simple. For more indepth steps refer here - http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is using a JSON parsing library such a [TouchJson](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).