# how to read an external mysql database

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to find how to read data from my database in my iphone app. The database is in my server, what I tried is similar to how I do that in Android (I'm not sure if is the best way):

```
NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.myip/notices.php";


NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Mysql response:is %@",serverOutput);
```

What I get is "Mysql response: is Array", what is true:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("database");


  $q = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM jos_content WHERE catid=12 AND state=1 AND DATE(publish_up) <= NOW() ORDER BY DATE(publish_up) DESC");

   while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

    $output[]=array("id" => $e['id'], "title" =>  utf8_encode($e['title']));
        echo $e;

print($output);

mysql_close();


?>
```

how should I do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your php print the data as JSON it will be much easier to deal with it

In your PHP use

Instead of

```
print($output);
```

use

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then in your iOS app you could use [this framewrok](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

Additional resources

- [How to parse JSON in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app)
- [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

To use SBJSon you would do the following

```
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
id object = [serverOutput JSONValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)object;
```

Now `dictionary` will contain the dictionary of values and keys

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite inexperienced. How can I use the framework? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm trying to do is add the framework to my project.

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/INSTALL.md but in the third step, where should I add the classes files?

Comment: new cuestion... NSLog(@"serverOutput %@", serverOutput);
    NSLog(@"Dictionary %@", dictionary); are the same, how it could be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13103/discussion-between-user1256477-and-omar-abdelhafith)

Comment: @user1256477 sorry i had an error in my code, please check the updated answer