# NSJSONSerialization not mapping boolean correctly

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsjsonserialization

I am reading data from [The Joys of Code](http://thejoysofcode.com/). The API returns data in JSON format where boolean variables are written as so:

```
{ "obj" :
   { 
      "sharing":false,
      "modified":"tuesday"
   }
}
```

Notice, sharing:false does **not** have quotation marks around the word *false*. I am then using NSJSONSerialization to parse this JSON into an object (NSDictionary in this example).

The problem is, "sharing":false or "sharing":true is always creating an object with sharing = 0, where 0 is an NSNumber with value 0.

My question is if this is valid JSON and NSJSONSerialization is not working correctly, or if the original JSON is invalid.

Comment: all's good with that. must be in how you attempt to read the dictionary gotten from the NSJSON

Comment: Ok. I should have checked this first. The problem is the server. It always returns false.

Comment: :) Im also often quick to blame system classes and am generally wrong :/

Comment: @PauldeLange, Thats what I told. If it is true, you will get it as 1. Not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization works fine for me with the above json (putting in false and true) :

```
NSData *json = [@"{ \"obj\" : \
                { \
                \"sharing\":false, \
                \"modified\":\"tuesday\" \
                } \
                }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:nil];
id sharing = dict [@"obj"][@"sharing"];
NSLog(@"%d", [sharing boolValue]);

json = [@"{ \"obj\" : \
                { \
                \"sharing\":true, \
                \"modified\":\"tuesday\" \
                } \
                }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:nil];
sharing = dict [@"obj"][@"sharing"];
NSLog(@"%d", [sharing boolValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just did exactly the same thing and it works. -> was a server bug always returning false.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid. You can always get `BOOL` from `NSNumber` as `[number boolValue]` and check it as

```
if ([number boolValue])
```

or

```
if ([number boolValue] == YES)
```

Comment: Ok so it is valid? Do you have a reference so I can query Apple about why NSJSONSerialization always maps it to NO?

Comment: @PauldeLange, It shouldn't be `NO` always.. It should be 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: @PauldeLange, Are you asking about technical support, https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/.. Just checked few other question about bool and json and looks like my above answer should help in this situation. See this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app.. Not sure why you are not getting true there..