# Getting data from response

Tags: ios, json

I am New to iOS developement.I have response string like below :

> {"7":"Afghanistan","8":"Albania","9":"Algeria","10":"Andorra","11":"Angola","12":"Antigua
>   and
>   Barbuda","13":"Argentina","14":"Armenia","15":"Austria","16":"Azerbaijan","17":"Bahamas","18":"Bahrain","19":"Bangladesh","20":"Barbados","21":"Belarus","22":"Belgium","23":"Belize","24":"Benin","25":"Bhutan","26":"Bolivia","27":"Bosnia
>   and
>   Herzegovina","28":"Botswana","29":"Brazil","30":"Brunei","31":"Bulgaria","32":"Burkina
>   Faso","33":"Burundi","34":"Cambodia","35":"Cameroon","36":"Canada","37":"Cape
>   Verde","38":"Central African
>   Republic","39":"Chad","40":"Chile","41":"China","42":"Colombia","43":"Comoros","44":"Costa
>   Rica","45":"Cote
>   d'Ivoire","46":"Croatia","47":"Cuba","48":"Cyprus","49":"Czech
>   Republic","50":"Democratic Republic of the
>   Congo","51":"Denmark","52":"Djibouti","53":"Dominica","54":"Dominican
>   Republic","55":"East Timor","56":"Ecuador","57":"Egypt","58":"El
>   Salvador","59":"Equatorial
>   Guinea","60":"Eritrea","61":"Estonia","62":"Ethiopia"}

Please help me to get country name list.

Comment: Try first something then bring the error here.

Comment: There must be a gazillinion answers here. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code to parse JSON Data above iOS 5

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JsonData options:0 error:&jsonError]; 
// here JsonData is nsmutabledata in which your response is append 
NSLog(@"%@",tempDict);
```

try this you will be succeed use iOS version 5.0 an above then 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know JSON parsing.

Search "iOS JSON Parsing" in google and you will get many tutorial for that.

LEt me list few here for you.

1 . [Working with JSON in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) 
2 . [JSON Framework for iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)
3 . [How to parse JSON in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app)

Learn JSON parsing try to do it in your app and if you face problem in that than post it here.

Answer (score 0):

you need first to do the following:
You embed this code in your viewdidLoad function:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:your URL path for json file"]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

then you have to add this function:

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData{
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
jsonResults = [json objectForKey:@"Content"];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

hope this will help you